# Htaccess- Redirect without URL change for error 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an error404.php page for all non-existing pages. Like If a page doesn't exist the page is redirected to error404.php using .htacces and its working for me. For example my URL is *www.mysite.com/Products* and by mistake user type *www.mysite.com/Product* then browser redirect user to *www.mysite.com/error404* and shows the same URL *www.mysite.com/error404* in URL box.

It becomes very annoying for user to type the same URL again to correct error. Now i want to redirect user to *www.mysite.com/error404* but in URL box i want to keep URL same the user typed i.e. *www.mysite.com/Product* or any other wrong.

My **.HTACCESS** for redirecting for error 404

```
Options +FollowSymLinks    
Options -Multiviews    
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 www.mysite.com/error404
```

I have also tried after searching for a long in Google...

```
ErrorDocument 404 error404
```

It doesn't change URL in URL box but it doesn't load error404 page content instead it just show error404 as text in whole browser window.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a relative path in your `.htaccess` file.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404
```

Comment: Exactly. What you were doing previous @ashish was creating what is known as a *Soft 404*. Soft 404 errors are problematic for search engines and are **not** advisable. The way that thebluefox has laid it out is correct and should work without issue :) Although I would add the extension at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks thebluefox i was not adding a /. So my code wasn't working...Thanks for your time...

Comment: My pleasure @Ashish - glad I could help!

Comment: @thickguru Okay i will add extension at end of file...As it is not going to be visible in URL bar....